# Google oauth with angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm trying to implement Google Oauth in angularjs. Here is the code for creating Google sign in button and the callback function for the same.

```
  // Google sign in intialization function
  <script type="text/javascript">
    a = function() {
     var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
     po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
     var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
   };
  </script>

  // Callback function after signin
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var access_token = ''
    function signinCallback(authResult) {
      console.log(authResult)
      if (authResult['status']['signed_in']) {
        access_token = authResult['access_token']
        if (window.location.pathname != "/album")
          window.location = "/#/albums";
        document.getElementById('signinButton').setAttribute('style', 'display: none');
      } else {
        console.log('Sign-in state: ' + authResult['error']);
      }
    }  
  </script>
```

Above code is executed on every page load. It stores the access token received from Google in a variable named access_token. I have an angular service which uses this access_token to call Google api. Here is the code for that -

```
picasaServices.factory('Phone', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default', {}, {
      query: {method: 'GET', params:{alt: 'json', access_token: access_token}, isArray: false}
    });
  }
]);
```

The problem is that by the time Google returns me the access token angular service executes itself with nil access_token. How can I solve this issue. Also I would like to if my whole approach is flawed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no simple answer. You need to deal with the possibility that your auth succeeds before Angular has initialised, and also the opposite (more likely).

There are several approaches you could take. One thing to consider is that if you try to call a Google API without an access token, you'll get a 401 error. A 401 could also happen naturally after one hour when the token expires. Therefore you need to code for a 401 response anyway, so you could use that same logic to deal with AngularJS initialising before the token is ready. One gotcha to be wary of is to not call auth multiple times.

One would hope that somebody in Google is creating an AngularJS friendly wrapper for the JS library.